# `GLIBC_2.28' not found in Ubuntu 16.04/14.04 in Travis

Tags: package-management, glibc

I have been using a binary to test in Travis, but it's been compiled with a new version of GLIBC apparently and now I get this all the time:

```
perl6: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by //tmp/whateverable/rakudo-moar/6f8442ada535b58806ee82d07124de45d5f6a739/lib/libmoar.so)
```

I can't seem to be able to find a repo for downloading that version for Ubuntu 18.04. So, assuming we're not able to ask the compiling team to compile the binary in some other way, is there any other solution to fixing this?

This [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1021420/glibc-2-25-not-found-on-ubuntu-windows-subsystem-for-linux) suggest to upgrade the OS, but I don't think that option is available in Travis. Any other idea?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL & off-topic (ESM releases are off-topic here too but have support elsewhere), however with regards 16.04 LTS have you tried using the snapped Travis  (https://snapcraft.io/search?q=travis)